# Length of an Arc of a Semicubical Parabola

Tags: calculus, integration

For a National Board Exam Review:

> Find the length of an arc in the first quadrant of the semi-cubical parabola $y^2 = x^3$ from the point where $x=0$ to the point where $x = 5/9$

Answer is $19/27$.

Let's get the $dy/dx$ form of the function;

$$y^2 = x^3$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3x^2}{y}$$

to get $ds$

$$ds = \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{3x^2}{y}\right)^2}$$

Length is therefore

$$\int^{5/9}_0  \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{3x^2}{y}\right)^2} dx =  0.598727$$

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible problem set is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should express $y$ first. $y=x^{3/2}$. Then
$$
y' = \frac32 x^{1/2}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{5/9} \sqrt{1 + y'^2}\,dx = \int_0^{5/9} \sqrt{1 + \frac94 x}\,dx = \left.\frac{8}{27}\left(1 + \frac94x\right)^{\!3/2}\right|_{x=0}^{x=5/9} = \frac{19}{27}
$$

Comment: it should be $y=\pm x^{3/2}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, nop. "Find the length of an arc in the first quadrant of..."

Comment: yes in the first quadrant, i have  misread it